# what is the difference between val and final in kotlin?

Tags: java, kotlin

In Kotlin, val is used to make variable/properties unchangeable, and then what is the use of final?
As i know that in java final is used for restricting inheritance or to make variable constant but in kotlin val is doing the constant part then what final will do in kotlin?

Comment: @Sweeper `final` is a (soft) keyword in Kotlin to prevent re-overriding an open method

Answer (score 6):

While `val` and `var` are used to distinguish read-only from read/write variables and properties, `open` and `final` define overridability.

Methods are `final` by default in Kotlin, but you can declare them `open` to allow subclasses to override the method. When this happens, subclasses can choose to prevent further overrides by adding the `final` keyword in addition to the `override` keyword:

```kotlin
open class Shape {
    open fun draw() { /*...*/ }
}
open class Rectangle() : Shape() {
    // subclasses of Rectangle can't override draw()
    final override fun draw() { /*...*/ }
}
```

See https://kotlinlang.org/docs/inheritance.html#overriding-methods

The same goes for defining and overriding *properties* too (see the [next section in the docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/inheritance.html#overriding-properties)):

```kotlin
open class Shape {
    open val vertexCount: Int = 0 // if this is final, we can't override it
}

class Rectangle : Shape() {
    override val vertexCount = 4
}
```